# How do constraints and autolayout work in Storyboards? Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I've watched several videos and read docs on how to use constraints and autolayout for my app.

I'm trying to make my design universal on all screen sizes.

The problem is, no matter what I do, my designs go all over the place and I have no idea why.

Example: I'll have a title that's supposed to be dead in the center of a screen, a set y-axis, and I'll turn aspect ratio on (or off - both don't work).

If the title is 100px from the left side and 100px from the right side, I'll add those constraints, and add Y axis constraints. I'll turn on aspect ratio, but have tried with it off. For the most part Y axis constraints work fine.

The title looks perfect in the default design I added constraints in, but if I run it in a different phone size, the title shoots 30 - 40% over to the left. I can't get any design to stick to the constraints.

I'm able to get a background image to work perfectly but other assets aren't working for me. It's getting pretty frustrating and I feel like I'm missing something obvious but nothing I find is giving me that missing link.

To sum it up: I've watched videos/read documentation on constraints and autolayout in storyboards for Xcode 9 but the moment I load up a different screen size my designs go haywire and don't stick to the constraints.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You've specified where you want the title to be (centre x and centre y), but you haven't said anything about the size of it. Is its size proportional to the superview's size or constant? Also note that the view's size is not the same as the text size of the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are working with constraints, always remember to specify these things:

- x coordinate
- y coordinate
- height
- width

If you specified all those things unambiguously, it will work. It's simple as that.

> I'll have a title that's supposed to be dead in the center of a screen, a set y-axis

By saying that, you have specified the x and y coordinates of the title. Good! Now you need to think about its size. How do you want its size to change? Here are some possibilities:

Size is constant:

[image]

Constant distance between left edge and left edge of screen, right edge and right edge of screen:

[image]

Width is half of screen width, height is half of screen height:

[image]

This last case can be a little tricky to do. You can add these kind of constraints by first adding an aspect ratio constraint, then setting different things in the property inspector:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm still having one issue - if I set x,y plus width,height, it looks perfect in the Storyboard for any phone size. It also looks perfect for every size on the simulator except for iPhone 5S / SE. When I open it up on the iPhone 5S simulator, instead of looking like the storyboard it shows my title like this: "TITL..." and my assets aren't conforming to the right sizes/layouts. Everything seems to be cut off. Any idea why it would appear differently in the storyboard vs the simulator with these constraints? I've cleaned the project, deleted the app, rebooted the sim, etc

Comment: @EnricoMatassa that means the label’s size is too small to contain all the text. You need to reduce the font size. You can either use a smaller constant font size, or dynamically calculate the font size. I remember there is a library called FittableFontLabel that does this.

Comment: Thank you, using a smaller constant font size helped and my problem is resolved!

Answer (score 0):

if you want If the title is 100px from the left side and 100px from the right side the add `center horizontal` to the super view .You can fix the `height` and `width`. And the `Y axis`.

It works for me.Thank you